# How to count items that belong to different groups in a list using python?

Tags: python

I have a list like what you see below and want to count how many times the first element of the list is appeared in relation to the first element of the tuple.

```
[['a', (2, 0.4632342), 0, 0],
 ['b', (2, 0.38278952), 0, 0],
 ['a', (0, 0.51164687), 0, 2],
 ['a', (2, 0.49053752), 0, 0],
 ['b', (6, 0.22554141), 0, 1],
 ['b', (11, 0.33718306), 0, 0],
 ['a', (0, 0.51265407), 0, 0],
 ['b', (0, 0.38063252), 0, 0],
 ['a', (2, 0.3401981), 0, 0],
 ['a', (6, 0.39846212), 0, 0]]
```

In the list above the results should look like this:

```
{'2':{'a':'3','b':'1'}, '0':{'a':'2' , 'b':'1'}, '6':{'a':'1', 'b':'1'}, '11':{'a':0 , 'b':'1'}}
```

or this:

```
{'2':{(a,3),(b,1)}, '0':{(a,2), (b,1)}, '6':{(a,1), (b,1)}, '11':{(a,0) , (b,1)}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter` and `itertools.groupby`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

f = lambda x: x[1][0]
d = {k: Counter(i[0] for i in g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=f), key=f)}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{0: Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1}), 2: Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1}), 11: Counter({'b': 1}), 6: Counter({'b': 1, 'a': 1})}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
l = [['a', (2, 0.4632342), 0, 0],
 ['b', (2, 0.38278952), 0, 0],
 ['a', (0, 0.51164687), 0, 2],
 ['a', (2, 0.49053752), 0, 0],
 ['b', (6, 0.22554141), 0, 1],
 ['b', (11, 0.33718306), 0, 0],
 ['a', (0, 0.51265407), 0, 0],
 ['b', (0, 0.38063252), 0, 0],
 ['a', (2, 0.3401981), 0, 0],
 ['a', (6, 0.39846212), 0, 0]]

unique_first_in_tuples = set([x[1][0] for x in l])
unique_first_in_lists = set([x[0] for x in l])

def counter(first_tuple):
    int_dict = {y : len([x for x in l if x[0]==y 
               and x[1][0]==first_tuple]) for y in 
               unique_first_in_lists}
    return int_dict

output = {x : counter(x) for x in unique_first_in_tuples}
```

Returns:

```
{0: {'a': 2, 'b': 1}, 2: {'a': 3, 'b': 1}, 11: {'a': 0, 'b': 1}, 6: {'a': 1, 'b': 1}}
```